# Android listview does not scroll when it is touched and pulled down at the same time

Tags: android, listview, scroll

There is a list view. I wrote this to stop the scroll when the user touches the screen while scrolling:

```
 public class OnTouchListner implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
             {
                businessResultListView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 
                return true;

            }  
         return false;
    }
 }
```

When i scroll the list down and when I touch the screen, the list view stops scrolling. But if I again try to scroll down / up, without lifting my finger from the scroll view, i am unable to scroll it.
If I take off my finger, then touch the list and then try to scroll, then I can do so.

How can I make my list scrollable after touch ?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Spooked ListView? ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Give the Scroll id like scroll_home

ScrollView  scroll_home;

scroll_home = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_event);

and on touch listview row add this function ...

this working well

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            scroll_home.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```